Ebay API call via JS on Zapier doesn't work
I have the following Ebay API call that has successfully worked on Postman
https://svcs.sandbox.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?Operation-Name=findItemsByKeywords&Service-Version=1.0.0&Security-AppName=PetrosBe-Sells-SBX-9ac2147f3-b674cf2c&Response-Data-Format=JSON&REST-Payload&keywords=laptop
While using the following Fetch JS code on Zapier,I got an error
const newOptions = {
    //...options,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `My Auth ID`,
    },
}
const res = await fetch('https://svcs.sandbox.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?Operation-Name=findItemsByKeywords&Service-Version=1.0.0&Security-AppName=xxx&Response-Data-Format=JSON&REST-Payload&keywords=laptop', newOptions);
const json = await res.json();
return json;


I have tried troubleshooting via Zapier, and tested on Postman and it is working. I expect the code to execute the API to search with sandbox account for specific keyword.
I need someone to help me identify the issue.

Are you getting any errors in the console?

Can you refer to the image above?

Looks like something may be blocking the connection, like a firewall.

Okay, I will try to allow my browser in Firewall

Do you have any experience solving such type of issues?

Sorry, I haven't dealt with firewalls and IDS for about 20 years.

It seems that this error is directly related to the Zappier timer. Since there are many XML items, it took a long time to finish executing. While Zappier's default timeout period is very small making inefficient for the JS code to run. I have tried with very few items on another Zap and worked successfully with the same JS code. I am looking for ways of assigning custom timeout period.
